# pgfplots: multiple legends or one legend and a heading

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

In my plot, I want my standard legend that says what value of c corresponds to what color.  However, I would also look to put the function in plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 1000,
    domain = -10:10,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 2,
    xmin = -7,
    xmax = 7
    ]
    \foreach \c/\col in {1/red, 2/blue, 3/green, 4/yellow}{
      \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[red, \col]
        {2 * \c / (exp(.5 * sqrt(\c) * x) + exp(-.5 * sqrt(\c) * x))^2};
      }
      \temp
    }
    \legend{$c = 1$\\ $c = 2$\\ $c = 3$\\ $c = 4$\\}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also want to put somewhere in the plot 
`\(u(\xi = x - ct) = \frac{c}{2}\sech^2\left[\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}(\xi - \xi_0)\right]\)`.

How can this be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Don't know about the main question, but for the last one you can add a node inside the axis using the `rel axis cs` coordinate system: `\node [right] at (rel axis cs:0,0.9) {\(u(\xi = x - ct) = \frac{c}{2}\sech^2\left[\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}(\xi - \xi_0)\right]\)};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. But if you want a heading within your legend it might be best to draw the legend yourself. Simply add `\labels` after each `\addplot` command and use `\ref{<label>}` to get the respective legend image for use in your hand made legend.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 1000,
    domain = -10:10,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 2,
    xmin = -7,
    xmax = 7
    ]
    \foreach \c/\col in {1/red, 2/blue, 3/green, 4/yellow}{
      \edef\temp{
        \noexpand\addplot[red, \col]
        {2 * \c / (exp(.5 * sqrt(\c) * x) + exp(-.5 * sqrt(\c) * x))^2};
        \noexpand\label{p\c}  % labels for later referencing
      }
      \temp
    }
    \node [draw,fill=white,anchor=north east] at (rel axis cs: 0.99,0.99) {\shortstack[l]{
        {\underline{Some Heading}} \\
        \ref{p1} $c=1$ \\
        \ref{p2} $c=2$ \\
        \ref{p3} $c=3$ \\
        \ref{p4} $c=4$}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]